# Traduction de l'adage « Beauty lies in the eye of the beholder. »

Tags: traduction, anglais

L'adage de langue anglaise « Beauty lies in the eye of the beholder. » trouve dans [Linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/beauty+is+in+the+eye+of+the+beholder.html) les formulations françaises suivantes, qui sont les formes les plus fidèles.

- *La beauté naît dans l’œil de celui qui la découvre.*
- *La beauté est dans l’œil de celui qui regarde.*

[reverso](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/anglais-francais/beauty+is+in+eye+of+the+beholder) propose « La beauté est affaire de gout. ». La maxime « Des  gouts et des couleurs on ne discute pas. » est un autre candidat sur lequel j'hésite aussi.

Cela semble indiquer qu'il n'existe pas en français un équivalent habituel pour cette phrase anglaise. L'information de background suivante situe ce proverbe comme ayant strictement une origine grecque. ([réf.](https://www.bloomsbury-international.com/student-ezone/idiom-of-the-week/100-beauty-is-in-the-eye-of-the-beholder/))

- *Something you say which means that different people have different opinions about what or who is beautiful.

  **Origin**

  It is unknown exactly where or how this idiom originated but it has been used in different forms since 3rd century BC when it first appeared in Greek. The first person to use it in the form we know today (“beauty is in the eye of the beholder”) was an author called Margaret Wolfe Hungerford [Irish novelist]. She included the phrase in her book ‘Molly Bawn’ (1878). It is another way of saying that beauty is subjective.*

J'ai pensé à la maxime « Chacun voit midi à sa porte. » mais je ne crois pas que les choix respectifs soient sur des niveaux suffisamment proches pour que cela soit une bonne traduction.

On trouve aussi en tant que traduction dans la référence ci-dessus « Il n'y a point de laides amours. » mais il me semble encore une fois que le niveau ne convienne pas ; on restreindrait l'idée à un cas plutôt particulier.

Quelqu'un aurait-il  conscience d'un adage existant qui conviendrait (par exemple l'un de ceux auxquels je réfère ci-dessus) et pourrait-il dire pourquoi, ou aurait-il une idée personnelle de formulation qui aurait suffisamment le style de l'adage et qui vaille la peine d'être considérée comme une possible traduction standard ?

Comment: Ceci n'est pas une traduction : l'essentiel est invisible pour les yeux.

Comment: @livresque C'est un point de vue très scientifique, que l'on peut concevoir facilement comme celui du scientifique. C'est une de vos idées personnelles ?

Comment: @livresque ce n'est pas une traduction pour sûr, mais cela n'a vraiment pas le même sens...

Comment: @livresque "L'essentiel est invisible pour les yeux" est une citation du Petit Prince de Saint Exupéry. ("On ne voit bien qu'avec le cœur, l'essentiel est invisible pour les yeux.")

Comment: Bien sûr que ça vient de Saint-Exupéry (ce n'est pas mon secret). A y penser, le sens n'est pas très loin du proverbe (et le temps que tu as perdu pour ta rose, etc) mais pas tout à fait.  C'est pour ça que j'ai noté dans le commentaire et pas comme réponse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La correspondance française la plus couramment utilisée en littérature pour la phrase proposée a été donnée dans la question:

*"La beauté est dans l’œil de celui qui regarde".*

Comment: Il serait intéressant de savoir d'où vous tenez ce fait; est-ce votre connaissance de la littérature qui vous  laisse une solide  conviction ?

Comment: C'est intuitif, en effet, mais je suis certain d'avoir rencontré cette expression exacte à plusieurs reprises dans mes lectures, sans toutefois me souvenir des références précises. On peut essayer de les retrouver, éventuellement...

Comment: Je ne m'avancerais pas à dire que c'est la plus utilisée en littérature car comme le souligne LPH c'est assez arrogant, mais néanmoins je suis assez d'accord, c'est cette formule que je suis habitué à entendre.

Comment: @LaurentS. — Vous voyez aussi de *l'arrogance* dans l'expression d'une des pensées les plus partagées par toutes les sagesses du monde ?

Answer (score 1):

Autre chose, depuis la page 135 [proverbes africains](https://www.evolution-101.com/proverbes-africains/) :

> La beauté est dans l’œil qui regarde, et non dans l’objet.

Answer (score 1):

Aussi:

> La beauté naît du regard de l’homme, mais le regard de l’homme naît de la nature. *Hubert Reeves*

Dans [pensées sur la nature](https://www.evolution-101.com/pensees-sur-la-nature/)

Answer (score 0):

Moi je dirais: La beauté est une affaire personnelle. Ou une question personnelle.

(Bien d'accord aussi pour la différence présentée par "De gustibus non est disputandum" -- en anglais, c'est plutôt "One does not (must not) quarrel over matters of taste"; et non ce dont il est question ici.)

Comment: On ne doit pas utiliser plusieurs formes pour une seule réponse, tout doit être inclu dans le même cadre. Je n'accorderai pas de vote à la présente partie ; vous devez la placer dans l'autre cadre.

Comment: oui, merci de regrouper les propositions dans une seule réponse plutôt que faire plusieurs micro-réponses.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://french.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/20433)